# How can I align the two tables?

Tags: tables, align

Why my tables below are not horizontally aligned?

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,xcolor={table,svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,fit,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[b]
\tikzset{na/.style={baseline=-.5ex}}
\begin{table}
$\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$C$ & $C_{1}$ & $C_{2}$ & \ldots & $C_{q^k}$
\tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (t1) {gi};\\ 
\hline
$v_{2}+C$ & $v_{2}+0$ & $v_{2}+C_{2}$ & \ldots & $v_{2}+C_{q^k}$  \\
\hline
$v_{3}+C$ & $v_{3}+0$ & $ \tikz[baseline]{
\node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (bug)
{$v_{3}+C_{2}$};
} $ & \ldots & $v_{3}+C_{q^k}$  \\
\hline
$\ldots$ & $\ldots$ & $\ldots$ & \ldots & $\ldots$  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\right\}$ $\omega(v_{i})\leq t$
$\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$v_{2}+C$ & $v_{2}+0  $   & $ \tikz[baseline]{
 \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (dug){$v_{2}+C_{2}$};} $  &       \ldots & $v_{2}+C_{q^k}$  \\ 
\hline
$v_{2}+C$ & $v_{2}+0$ & $v_{2}+C_{2}$ & \ldots & $v_{2}+C_{q^k}$  \\
 \hline
$v_{2}+C$ & $v_{2}+0$ & $v_{2}+C_{2}$ & \ldots & $v_{2}+C_{q^k}$  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\right\}$ $\omega(v_{i}) > t$
\end{table}
1 \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (booh) {};

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path[very thick,->] (t1) edge [bend right] (bug);
\path[very thick,->] (booh) edge [bend left] (bug);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your case I think using `array` better  then `tabular`.

Answer (score 2):

cause of your problem is already identified in JMP answer (his is bit me in fast response ...), so I only add some optimization to your code (whic consume this three minutes :-) ):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                fit,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}
\tikzset{
every picture/.style = {remember picture},
           na/.style = {baseline=-.5ex}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[b]
\qquad$\left.\begin{array}{|*{5}{c|}}
    \hline
C       &   C_{1}   &   C_{2}   &   \ldots
            &   C_{q^k}\tikz[na]\node[coordinate] (t1) {gi};    \\
    \hline
v_{2}+C & v_{2}+0   &   \tikz[baseline]{
                        \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (bug)
                        {$v_{2}+C_{2}$};}   
                                &   \ldots 
            &   v_{2}+C_{q^k}                               \\
    \hline
v_2+C   &   v_2+0   & v_2+C_2   & \ldots 
            & v_{2}+C_{q^k}                                 \\
    \hline
v_{2}+C & v_{2}+0   & v_2+C_2   & \ldots 
            & v_{2}+C_{q^k}                                 \\
    \hline
\end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$

\qquad$\left.
\begin{array}{|*{5}{c|}}
\hline
v_{2}+C &   v_{2}+0 &   \tikz[baseline]{
                        \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (dug)
                        {$v_{2}+C_{2}$};}   
                                &   \ldots 
            &   v_{2}+C_{q^k}                               \\
    \hline
v_{2}+C & v_{2}+0   & v_2+C_2   &   \ldots 
            & v_{2}+C_{q^k}                                 \\
    \hline
v_{2}+C & v_{2}+0   & v_2+C_2   &   \ldots 
            & v_{2}+C_{q^k}                                 \\
    \hline
\end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$

    \vspace{2ex}
1 \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (booh) {};

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[very thick,->] (t1)   edge [bend right] (bug);
    \path[very thick,->] (booh) edge [bend  left] (bug);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is almost the same (I only select different distance drom left border to tables:

[image]

Main difference to your code is that instead `tabular` I use `array`. So `$` is needed only in beginning and end of the array and in node's content.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Latex to start a new paragraph between the tables, otherwise it tries to typeset your code somehow by adding whitespace.

```
\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,xcolor={table,svgnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,fit,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,angles,quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[b]
\tikzset{na/.style={baseline=-.5ex}}
\begin{table}
$\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$C$ & $C_{1}$ & $C_{2}$ & \ldots & $C_{q^k}$
\tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (t1) {gi};\\ 
\hline
$v_{2}+C$ & $v_{2}+0$ & $v_{2}+C_{2}$ & \ldots & $v_{2}+C_{q^k}$  \\
\hline
$v_{3}+C$ & $v_{3}+0$ & $ \tikz[baseline]{
\node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (bug)
{$v_{3}+C_{2}$};
} $ & \ldots & $v_{3}+C_{q^k}$  \\
\hline
$\ldots$ & $\ldots$ & $\ldots$ & \ldots & $\ldots$  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\right\}$ $\omega(v_{i})\leq t$

$\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\left.
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
$v_{2}+C$ & $v_{2}+0  $   & $ \tikz[baseline]{
 \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (dug){$v_{2}+C_{2}$};} $  &       \ldots & $v_{2}+C_{q^k}$  \\ 
\hline
$v_{2}+C$ & $v_{2}+0$ & $v_{2}+C_{2}$ & \ldots & $v_{2}+C_{q^k}$  \\
 \hline
$v_{2}+C$ & $v_{2}+0$ & $v_{2}+C_{2}$ & \ldots & $v_{2}+C_{q^k}$  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}\right\}$ $\omega(v_{i}) > t$
\end{table}
1 \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (booh) {};

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path[very thick,->] (t1) edge [bend right] (bug);
\path[very thick,->] (booh) edge [bend left] (bug);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]