# How I can align 2 arrays?

Tags: beamer, color

I want to get rid of indentation on the first image to make it as a second.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
            backgrounds,
            calc,
            decorations.pathreplacing,
            fit,
            arrows,
            positioning,
            quotes,
            shapes}
\tikzset{
every picture/.style = {remember picture},
       na/.style = {baseline=-.5ex}
    }
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

\qquad$\left.
\begin{array}{|*{5}{c|}}
\hline
C &   C_{1}   &    \tikz[baseline]{
                    \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (table)              {$C_{2}$};}  &   \ldots
        &   C_{q^k}  \\
        \hline
        \end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$
         \\
         \qquad$\left.
         \begin{array}{|*{5}{c|}}
\hline
C       &   C_{1}   &    \tikz[baseline]{
                    \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (table)      {$C_{2}$};}  &   \ldots
        &   C_{q^k}\tikz[na]\node[coordinate] (t1) {gi};    \\
\hline
v_{2}+C & v_{2}+0   &   \tikz[baseline]{
                    \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (bug)
                    {$v_{2}+C_{2}$};}   
                            &   \ldots 
        &   v_{2}+C_{q^k}                               \\
\hline
\ldots  &   \ldots   & \ldots  & \ldots 
        & \ldots                                 \\
\hline
v_{j}+C & v_{j}+0   & v_j+C_2   & \ldots 
        & v_{j}+C_{q^k}                                 \\
\hline
\end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$

\qquad$\left.
\begin{array}{|*{5}{c|}}
\hline
\ldots  &   \ldots   & \ldots  & \ldots 
        & \ldots                                 \\
\hline
v_{2}+C &   v_{2}+0 &   \tikz[baseline]{
                    \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (dug)
                    {$v_{2}+C_{2}$};}   
                            &   \ldots 
        &   v_{2}+C_{q^k}                               \\
\hline
v_{l}+C & v_{l}+0   & v_l+C_l   &   \ldots 
        & v_{l}+C_{q^k}                                 \\
\hline
\end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: I have]

[image: I want]

Comment: Which column you like to colored?

Comment: And I'm just curious: in your question you use one answer on your question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303312/how-can-i-align-the-two-tables, but no one of recieved you didn't accepted ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edit of question, it appear as total new and different question. SO I decided to respond to it with new answer in which I focus on design of tree tables with equal width of columns. Coloring is already solved in my first answer, and equal horizontal positioning in my answer on your question ["How can I align the two tables?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303312/how-can-i-align-the-two-tables) (as I see from your question, you use my provided solution, however you didn't accept answer as useful for you ... this is not very nice from you).

To make three different tables with equal width of columns (which have different wide content) seems to be among possible solutions the simplest one with external (central) defined widths like

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{16mm}<{$}}
```

With this column type the advantage of  `array` disappear. Anyway let be used further. New, minimal code for this case is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{16mm}<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

\qquad$\left.
\begin{array}{|C|C|>{\columncolor{red!20}}C|c|C|}
    \hline
C       &   C_1     &   C_2     &   \ldots  &   C_{q^k}     \\
    \hline
\end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$

\vskip-1.5ex
\qquad$\left.
\begin{array}{|C|C|>{\columncolor{red!20}}C|c|C|}
    \hline
C       &   C_1     &   C_2     &   \ldots  &   C_{q^k}     \\
    \hline
v_2+C   &   v_2+0   &   v_2+C_2 &   \ldots  &   v_2+C_{q^k} \\
    \hline
\ldots  &   \ldots  & \ldots    &   \ldots  &   \ldots      \\
    \hline
v_j+C   &   v_j+0   &   v_j+C_2 &   \ldots  & v_j+C_{q^k}   \\
    \hline
\end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$

%\vskip-1.5ex
\qquad$\left.
\begin{array}{|C|C|C|c|C|}
    \hline
\ldots  &   \ldots  &   \ldots  &   \ldots  &   \ldots      \\
    \hline
v_2+C   &   v_2+0   &   v_2+C_2 &   \ldots  &   v_2+C_{q^k} \\
    \hline
v_l+C   &   v_l+0   &   v_l+C_l &   \ldots  &   v_l+C_{q^k} \\
    \hline
\end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$

 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And result:

[image]

I must confess, that I'm not sure, what actually is your question. So, above solution is based on guessing. With previous answers you already receive usable instructions/help how to positioned tables and colored whole column.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what was required. 
I have noted by tick your answer and it was useful for me.
I can still somehow to thank you? 
I'm just not aware of the rules of this site,

Answer (score 6):

For example, if you would like to color the first column of the second table:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
            backgrounds,
            calc,
            decorations.pathreplacing,
            fit,
            arrows,
            positioning,
            quotes,
            shapes}
\tikzset{
every picture/.style = {remember picture},
       na/.style = {baseline=-.5ex}
    }
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

\qquad$\left.
\begin{array}{|*{5}{c|}}
\hline
C &   C_{1}   &    \tikz[baseline]{
                    \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (table)              {$C_{2}$};}  &   \ldots
        &   C_{q^k}  \\
        \hline
        \end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$
         \\
         \qquad$\left.
         \begin{array}{|>{\columncolor{red!20}}c|*{4}{c|}}
\hline
C       &   C_{1}   &    \tikz[baseline]{
                    \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (table)      {$C_{2}$};}  &   \ldots
        &   C_{q^k}\tikz[na]\node[coordinate] (t1) {gi};    \\
\hline
v_{2}+C & v_{2}+0   &   \tikz[baseline]{
                    \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (bug)
                    {$v_{2}+C_{2}$};}
                            &   \ldots
        &   v_{2}+C_{q^k}                               \\
\hline
\ldots  &   \ldots   & \ldots  & \ldots
        & \ldots                                 \\
\hline
v_{j}+C & v_{j}+0   & v_j+C_2   & \ldots
        & v_{j}+C_{q^k}                                 \\
\hline
\end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$

\qquad$\left.
\begin{array}{|*{5}{c|}}
\hline
\ldots  &   \ldots   & \ldots  & \ldots
        & \ldots                                 \\
\hline
v_{2}+C &   v_{2}+0 &   \tikz[baseline]{
                    \node[rounded corners,fill=red!15,anchor=base] (dug)
                    {$v_{2}+C_{2}$};}
                            &   \ldots
        &   v_{2}+C_{q^k}                               \\
\hline
v_{l}+C & v_{l}+0   & v_l+C_l   &   \ldots
        & v_{l}+C_{q^k}                                 \\
\hline
\end{array}\right\} \omega(v_{i}) > t$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, to color columns you need to add option `xcolor={dvipsnames,table}` to the `beamer` document class and than use the macro `\columncolor{<color>}` in the column which you would like to have colored.

[image]

Comment: You don't actually *have* to add `dvipsnames` unless you want those particular colours ;).

Comment: Feel free to roll back if you object in any way to my edit.

Comment: @cfr, thank you very much to improve my answer, Now it can be read and understand  (my English is  many time quit rude :-( )

Comment: It wasn't *rude* at all! Well, not in the usual sense of the term. Maybe 'rude' in the sense of 'rude health' - but that would hardly be a bad thing! I just adjusted its flow a little when it seemed to get a bit stuck.

Comment: Thanks! But how I can do this? Align first 2 arrays 
[example](https://preview.overleaf.com/public/gdqnvwbzdgzn/images/d30e7be48f13877557ad00dd7ccb49fb9196bfc1.jpeg).

Comment: Similar as for the first column in given example. For example, for the third column to be in `blue!20` color `\begin{array}{|c|c|>{\columncolor{blue!20}}c|c|}`

Comment: sorry for my english but I asked not about color. I need align first 2 arrays horizontally. like on 
[picture](https://preview.overleaf.com/public/gdqnvwbzdgzn/images/d30e7be48f13877557ad00dd7ccb49fb9196bfc1.jpeg).

Comment: This was your first question on which I already answered. Even more, as I see, you use this answer in this question (without accepting my answer as useful :-( ) which solve problem mentioned in your last comment. So I'm confused now, what is actually your question. Please, edit your question and "clear and loudly" describe your problem with showing expected result and your effort what you try so far. Unfortunately my "crystal ball" is broken, so I can't see what you have in mind :-)

Comment: I tried to edit the question. I hope it was clear